# Can I reuse the id of a select element inside a .change function for that element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a number of selects and when they change value I store the new value in windows local storage. All my functions repeat the same logic. Is there some way that I could combine these three into one. Note that the windows local storage name is always the same as the element ID of the select.

```
var store = window.localStorage;

$('#AccountID')
   .change(function () {
       store.setItem('AccountID', $(this).val());
    });

$('#ExamID')
   .change(function () {
       store.setItem('ExamID', $(this).val());
    });

$('#PageID')
   .change(function () {
       store.setItem('PageID', $(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: And what's the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to assign a CSS class to every element you want to track, then just bind the single event handler.

```
var store = window.localStorage;

$('select.tracked').change(function(){
    store.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
});
```

adjust the selector as needed to match the types of elements you want to track e.g. `:input`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#AccountID, #ExamID,#PageID')
   .change(function () {store.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could easily shorten this using the element's id as the key for the local storage, like this:

```
var store = window.localStorage;

$('#AccountID, #ExamID, #PageID').change(function() {
  store.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be over simplifying this (as I usually do :)

But this may be of some assistance-

```
$('#AccountID')
   .change(function () {
       store.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
    });
```

In the same way that you use `$(this).val()` to extract the value of the current element, you can use `$(this).attr('id')` to retrieve the `id` of the current element and use it as the key for local storage...

So to make your selector more generic you could simply capture a `.change()` event for **all** select elements -

```
$('select')
   .change(function () {
       store.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
    });
```

If that is a little too broad for you, you can always give your relevant select elements matching classes or even specify all of your select elements in one selector -

`$('#AccountID, #ExamID, #PageID, #anotherSelect, #...')`